# java spring resource folder: FileNotFoundException

Tags: java, spring

I cannot access files in resource directory. What is the problem?

in `servlet-context.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing infrastructure -->

    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <annotation-driven />

    <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
    <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </beans:bean>   

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.example.test" />

</beans:beans>
```

in 'HomeController.java'

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String home(Locale locale, Model model) {

    File file = new File("/resources/sample/text.txt");
    if (file.exists()) {
        logger.info("file found.");
    } else {
        logger.info("file not found.");
    }

    return "home";
}
```

in web.xml (default)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- Processes application requests -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: If this is a Unix/Linux base file system, setting the initial "/" will make it start at the root level of the file system. Have you tried removing it? Use "resources/sample/text.txt"

Comment: @JorgeGarita yes, I tried...

Comment: what is your web.xml mapping

Comment: Have you tried `InputStream is = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(sample/text.text)` ?

Comment: I could finally open resource files using absolute path "/tmp/resources/text.txt". Maybe that is the wrong answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oups, that is **not** the correct way to access resources in a web application.

First, your resource paths are relative to the ServetContext path, so you should not try to use them as file system absolute paths. But in addition, you cannot be sure that they exist as true files.

The servlet specifications allow a servlet container not to explode a war file, prodided it is able to correctly serve resources through `ServletContext.getResourceAsStream(java.lang.String path)`

That means that you should only use resources as read-only through `ServletContext.getResourceAsStream(java.lang.String path)` and never try to use them as true files.